# How to manage Schema Drift while streaming to BigQuery sharded table

Tags: google-bigquery

We are new to BigQuery and are trying to figure out the best way to use it for real time analytics.  We are sending a stream of logs from our back-end services to Kafka, and we want to stream those into BigQuery using streaming inserts.  For queryability we are both partitioning by time, and sharding tables by event type (for use with wildcard queries). We put a view overtop of the family of tables created so that they look like 1 table and use the _TABLE_SUFFIX (well, when they roll out the feature, for now using UNION ALL) and _PARTITIONTIME columns to reduce the set of rows scanned for queries.  So far so good.

What we are unsure of how to handle properly is schema changes. The schema of our log messages changes frequently. Having a manual process to keep BigQuery in sync is not tenable. Ideally our streaming pipeline would detect the change and apply the schema update (for adding columns) or table creation (for adding an event type) as necessary. We have tooling up-stream so that we know all schema updates will be backwards compatible.

My understanding is that all of the shards must have the same schema. How do we apply the schema update in such a fashion that:

1. We don't break queries that are run during the update.
2. We don't break streaming inserts.

Is #1 possible? I don't believe we can atomically change the schema of all the sharded tables.

For #2 I presume we have to stop our streaming pipelines while the schema update process is occurring.

Thanks,
--Ben

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard tables with _TABLE_SUFFIX is available https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables and you can use it even if the schemas of the tables are different, they just need to have compatible schemas. With UNION ALL, you need all the tables to have the same schema so it will not work if you're updating schemas at the same time.
Streaming insert will also work if you only specify a subset of fields. However you cannot add new fields as part of the streaming insert, you'll have to update table first and then insert the data with new schema.

Comment: Unfortunately wildcard tables don't currently work with date partitioned tables.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905833

Comment: From the comments on the bug, the feature was temporary broken and should be fixed soon.

Comment: Also if you run a query using UNION ALL and start updating the tables after the query started execution, the query will not fail and will use a version of the tables that existed when query started.